# How to write this URL rewrite rule to trucate unwanted content?

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting

Iam using apache mod_rewrite to redirect some URL. I been able to some of the URLS but none of my rules are able to caprure this

http://192.23.70.11/mome/GIS%20Endo/%2Fhome%2FGIS%2520Endo%2F

and redirect it to

http://192.23.70.11/mome/GIS%20Endo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your first rule in site root .htaccess or Apache config:

```
# this goes in httpd.conf
AllowEncodedSlashes On

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(/?mome/[^/]+)/.+$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

This will match any URI starting with `/mome` and will truncate anything after 2nd path component.

Comment: Doesn't work it says "The requested URL /mome/GIS Endo//home/GIS%20Endo/ was not found on this server."

Comment: So it is not truncating the string. Wonder if the encoded values in the string are causing any problems.

Comment: Actually it worked but I had to set AllowEncodedSlashes On. Thanks!